# Why the groupbox design time does not come visible in run time?

Tags: c#, groupbox

I have a groupbox created invisible in design time. Within the program when I need I would make it visible but it doesn't.  If I do it visible in design time I can make it invisible or visible in run time. Is there any reason or should i declare something in implementation ?

Comment: I found the reason. Groupbox lays on two panels which are always visible. When I create it in visible state in desing time I change it's state invisible in form load, and when I need it I put it in visible state, it becomes visible. It works well.

But When I create with invisible state and when I put it within program in visible state it lays behind 2 panels. And I don't know the reason. 

The code is groupBox2.visible = true; that's all!

Comment: I change the groupbox with panel here is the two views

This is the view with panel invisible in design time http://www.turcguide.com/stack/label.jpg
This is the view with panel visible in design time
http://www.turcguide.com/stack/label1.jpg

In first screenshot(panel.jpg) panel is hidden by two others panels.

Comment: Sorry i could'nt see your images provided in link, might be broken.could you please check?

Comment: Sorry I typed label instead of panel

http://www.turcguide.com/stack/panel.jpg
http://www.turcguide.com/stack/panel1.jpg